# Webkit issue: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Webkit for some reason isn't seeing jquery.

jQuery loads first in the footer before all other JS, but some of the subsequent scripts fail with:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function
```

I can see/load jquery in Chrome using the path specified in the `<script>` tag:

```
domain.com/js/jquery.js
```

The pages that load look identical in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but for some reason only Firefox sees jQuery.

I've found similar answers but don't understand them or don't understand how the apply to this situation sorry, any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: do you use fancybox before loading jQuery?

Comment: You need to show order of scripts also.

Comment: post the code, and not what do you think the code doing  :-)

Comment: Check in source page that it doesn't load 2 instances of jQuery.

Comment: Press F12 when viewing in the browser, do you see any errors in the console besides the ones you've posted? Maybe referencing jQuery with wrong URL path or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, turned out there was some inline jquery (via a CMS block template) which was failing now that jquery was being loaded in the footer. Have up-voted the answer that lead me to discover this